# jquery append function isnt working

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add a div and a span to an image on click and then remove it on the span click.

```
   <div id="gallery" align="center">    

        <img  src="http://www.frontpagejunky.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05.jpg" class="img-view" width="150px" height="150px" />
</div>
```

The jquery:

```
           $(document).ready(function(){
              $('.img-view').click(function(){
                  var img=$(this).after('<span id="close">X Close</span>').wrap("<div id='pop-up' style='display:block'/>").clone();
                  $('#gallery').append(img);
              });

             $('#close').live("click",function(){
                 $('#pop-up').remove();
                  $('#close').remove();

             });

       });
    </script>
```

The problem that I am having is that the span doesn't get wrapped in the div, but only the image does, and the span is only appended after the image is wrapped. 
The second problem is when I click the #close, the div and the button disappear, but when I click again on the .img-view , they don't regenerate/reappear. why does that happen?

**UPDATE**

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
              $('.img-view').click(function(){
                  var img=$(this).clone();
                   img= img.after('<span class="close">X Close</span>');
                   img=img.wrap("<div class='pop-up' style='display:block'/>"); 
                  $('#gallery').append(img);
              });

             $('.close').live("click",function(){
                 $('.pop-up').remove();
                  $('.close').remove();

             });

       });
```

But now the pop up div doesn't wrap the image element !?!

Comment: $ not required with img in $(img).

Comment: Watchout! you are using `#pop-up` and `#close` multiple times. ID's should be unique. They can not be repeated. You can use class instead of ids and find nearest `.pop-up` and `.close` while removing.

Comment: I know , but I want the image to pop up once, and close down... I dont want two elements to be generated on the screen

Comment: about update: because The close button is added after `$(this)`. and the `.wrap` is also applied to `$(this)`. so the close button remains outside

Comment: Chaining is cool but your $(this).after().wrap().clone(); is pretty confusing. Try making a clone first and change that clone in a new line of code. It probably even solves your problem.(I upvoted Imdad's comment for this)

Comment: okay, I will try to follow your advice

Comment: See my update, The problem now, is that the img variable/element doesnt get wrapped with the div

Comment: Please post a jsFiddle it will be solved in few seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use wrap on element that are not in the dom. You can either create a new element that will be your wrapper and hook everything to that wrapper or first insert your img to the dom and then wrap it.

You should do either of these 2 options, first being best, before you add the span with the X.

Comment: Yeah, I thought it was weird, when I tried to wrap two elements at once

Answer (score 1):

Use this one:

```
$('#gallery').append(img);
```

Instead of:

```
$('#gallery').append($(img));
```

Comment: and why when I remove an element, I cant append it again?

Comment: There is no restriction like that you can append but can you post html and jquery code that how you are trying to add and remove?

Comment: The close span isnt coming after the image but after the pop up div, that doesnt solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

Your chaining is a bit off, 
`$(this).after('<span id="close">X Close</span>')` returns `$(this)`(which is the image),  so `$(this).after('<span id="close">X Close</span>').wrap("<div id='pop-up' style='display:block'/>")` wraps the div around the image then returns `$(this)`, 
`$(this).after('<span id="close">X Close</span>').wrap("<div id='pop-up' style='display:block'/>").clone()` returns a clone of $(this)

This might help

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.img-view').on('click', function(e){
        $("<div id='pop-up' style='display:block'/>").appendTo('#gallery').append('<span id="close">X Close</span>').find('#close').append(this);           
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
    $('#close').live("click",function(){
        $(this).find('.img-view').appendTo('#gallery');
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
});
```

---

EDIT

The reason this wasn't working was because the click handler on #close was being called since it became a parent of .img-view, to prevent this I added a `stopPropagation()`, also changed the code so text `X Close` is removed.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sVVVS/)

Comment: lol..but I want the image to be put inside the pop pu too,,append(this) isnt working

Comment: that doesnt work, now it adds many close buttons inside the image, but they dont work,,and no image is added